# How can I set CloudFront createInvalidation lambda params to remove all?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

I'm serving some websites by S3 static hosting.

I want to remove **all** from the CloudFront distribution by createInvalidation method with lambda. 
 (After running the pipeline to update those buckets.)

- Q1. I'm confused which value is correct for Quantity in this case...
- Q2. Can I use `"/*"` in the Items array as an item? or just `"/*"` string instead of the array?

Can I use incorrect huge number (ex, 1000 or 10000) for Quantity? 
or Do I need to check the whole file counts in S3 bucket?

Because I need to add this lambda in a stepfunction state machine, using CLI is not a solution for me.

```
const invalidationParams = {
        DistributionId: "XXXX",
        InvalidationBatch: {
            CallerReference: Date.now().toString(),
            Paths: {
                Quantity: ???,
                Items: [
                    "/*", // maybe?
                 ]
            }
        }
    };
```

or... Do you recommend to use iteration of CLI command...?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was too hurry to create the question...

I tried to create the invalidations by CLI during the waiting, 
and its response gave me the answer.

I got below by the CLI command `aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id {DISTRIBUTION_ID} --paths "/*"`

```
{
    "Location": "https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/blahblah",
    "Invalidation": {
        "Id": "blahblah",
        "Status": "InProgress",
        "CreateTime": "2021-10-07T14:01:42.406000+00:00",
        "InvalidationBatch": {
            "Paths": {
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Items": [
                    "/*"
                ]
            },
            "CallerReference": "cli-1633615280-121576"
        }
    }
}
```

So, it means, I can set the Quantity as 1 in lambda.
And also can use the "/*" in the array.

I added this for someone like me